# Build Robotium Test Project from command line

Tags: android, eclipse, jenkins, robotium

I'm exploring the Android build system and want to move everything to Jenkins server. I've managed to build the project and run instrumentation tests (white box testing) on Jenkins. And now stuck at the integration testing..

I followed the [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumTutorials) to create a Android Test Project on Eclipse. And the tests run successfully. But I need to be able to run it from command line so that I can trigger the tests on Jenkins.

If I run the project on Eclipse first, and later I will be able to use the command:

> adb shell am instrument -w com.example.uitests/Android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

However, if just want to start everything from command line, I don't know how to build the project...It looks like there's no build file generated by Eclipse..

Do I need to use ant or gradle? if so, what's the right way of doing so?

**Edit:**

When calling to list all instrumentation info

> adb shell pm list instrumentation

I'm able to find my tests package:

> instrumentation:com.example.uitests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
>   (target=com.exmaple.android)

But when running the first command, I get

> INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
>   INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for:
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.uitests/Android.test.InstrumentationTestRunnerpm}
>   INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1 android.util.AndroidException:
>   INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED:
>   com.android.uitests/Android.test.InstrumentationTestRunnerpm
>     at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:802)    at
>   com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:242)     at
>   com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)  at
>   com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:75)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have now is to add ant build.xml to this test project, follow the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html)

> android update project --name  --target 
>   --path

After updating the project, I'm able to build and install the apk to emulators

> ant clean debug install